# minecraft - Always active repeating command block doesn't bypass given command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When I enter the following command in a Repeating Command Block (always active), nothing happens.

```
execute if block ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:dropper{Items:[{Slot:0,id:"minecraft:redstone",Count:1},{Slot:1,id:"minecraft:redstone",Count:1},{Slot:2,id:"minecraft:redstone",Count:1},{Slot:3,id:"minecraft:redstone",Count:1},{Slot:4,id:"minecraft:iron_axe",Count:1},{Slot:5,id:"minecraft:redstone",Count:1},{Slot:6,id:"minecraft:redstone",Count:1},{Slot:7,id:"minecraft:redstone",Count:1},{Slot:8,id:"minecraft:redstone",Count:1}]} run setblock ~ ~1 ~ minecraft:dropper{Items:[{Slot:4,id:"minecraft:iron_axe",Count:1,tag:{Unbreakable:1,display:{Name:"{\"text\":\"UnbreakableAxe\",\"italic\":\"false\",\"bold\":\"true\",\"color\":\"gold\"}"}}}]} replace
```

All following requirements of the command are fulfilled:

- A dropper on top of the command block (fulfills relative coordinate **~ ~1 ~**)
- Dropper contains redstones on slot 1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9 and an iron axe on slot 5. (subtract 1 for each slot for the command)

Am I doing something wrong? I'm assuming there is something wrong in the command, though, I still don't know.

Comment: Instead of `Slot:0`, use `Slot:0b`. See the difference?

Comment: @Robomike `Count:1b` is also needed, aparently. Tough the color format is not correct to, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @Robomike I have already tried adding `b`s on the numbers, still not solving the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to create a new world, and it worked. I don't know what happened, but I'm assuming that the world went broken.